# Why is shapefile not recognised by Mason?

Tags: qgis, convert, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap, mif

I have a shapefile of an [Ordnance Survey Mastermap ITN](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/itn-layer.html) road network that I am trying to load into an agent-based modelling software called [Mason](https://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/). When I try to run my model I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: shpFile
>   is null; likely file not found

My model works fine with every other road network ([OS Mastermap Meridian 2](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/meridian2.html), [Boundary-Line](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html) etc.) I can throw at it and can display other shapefiles I'm using. All the shapefiles show up in QGIS just fine.

The OS ITN data was downloaded as a compressed **.gz** file, with two **GML** files within. These were were then converted to **.MIF/.MID** using [OSM2MIF](http://freemappingtools.yolasite.com/osm2mif.php). These were then loaded into QGIS and saved as **.SHP** (right click>Save As...>ESRI Shapefile).

In QGIS and ArcMap the resultant shapefile of the road network looks as expected and all the metadata is present. However, when I try to load it using my Mason model, it fails. It seems to *only* fail using *this* shapefile so I know it's *not* my model and is thus a problem with the shapefile.

Have I done something wrong during the conversion? Does anyone know how best to use [Ordnance Survey Mastermap ITN](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/itn-layer.html) and convert to usable shapefiles?

Comment: "Shapefile" is a misnomer, because it's actually 3-5 (and sometimes quite a few more) files. Your error message states that one or more are missing, so you should be certain that you have at least .shx, .dbf, and .prj with the same prefix as the .shp.

Comment: @Vince this is unlikely, because it is visible in ArcMap. I think it's good idea to export it to a new one: short name, z and m disabled

Comment: It's unclear from the question if the shapefile is being used *in situ* or bundled in some fashion for this modelling tool.

Comment: @Vince Yes, I have a .shx, .shp, dbf, .prj, qpj and a .cpg. The files are being used _in situ_, with the code referencing the files where they are: 'URL roadGeometry=NorfolkCSV.class.getResource("/Users/User/Downloads/ITN_1.shp"); ShapeFileImporter.read(roadGeometry, roads);'

Comment: @FelixIP, z and m disabled?

Comment: @KJGarbutt ope attribute table and check what field Shape says. If it Polyline, forget about zm, if PolylineZM goto environment and set z m flags to disable. Use copyfeatures tool to copy shapefile to another. Keep name short, e.g. theme1.shp. My guess that 3rd party software can't handle z-enabled shapes, which is very often a case with them.

Comment: Also check that table has at least 1 more field in addition to fid and shape

Comment: @FelixIP Have checked the attribute table and I don't have a 'shape' field. It doesn't seem to be present in the original files or my converted ones. I do have plenty of other fields in the attributes though. See [here](http://imgur.com/MEhj3iZ). I have copied the attributes to another, as suggested, and my model does open and run. However, I think the CRS are all wrong now as my boundary and flood maps are small and in the corner of the screen and the new road network is not visible: see [here](http://imgur.com/arpjahq).

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain details about the coordinate reference system differences. The dBase file *never* contains a geometry column; only shapefile-aware tools display it that way.

Comment: @KJGarbutt it is a different question now, isnt it? So post it separately